# Como imprimir la respuesta de un servlet en un jsp por medio de un alert

Tags: java, jsp

Hola verán estoy haciendo unos ejercicios de la universidad para la clase de programacion en java.

Lo que tengo que hacer en este es un login, entonces ingreso el usuario y una contraseña, que van en 2 cajas de texto que están en un jsp, al apretar el boton manda los datos a un servlet que valida y manda la respuesta nuevamente a la vista (jsp), que tiene que salír por medio de un alert en la pantalla al usuario.

Mi codigo es así:

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>LOGIN</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>LOGIN</h1>
        <h4>Ingrese los datos que se solicitan: </h4>

        <!-- este es el form que se encarga de encapsular los textbox y los botones, este manda la informacion de estos al servlet -->
        <form name="idLogin" action="srvLogin" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="txtUsuario" value="" placeholder="NOMBRE DE USUARIO"/><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="txtPass" value="" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA"/><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Calcular" name="btnlog" /> <!-- este es el boton que desencadena el evento-->
        </form>
        <% //si ls respuesta de mi servlet es diferente a vacio
            if(request.getAttribute("mensaje")!=null) 
            {  //tendrìa que mandar a imprimir por medio del alert de abajo el mensaje de acceso correcto o incorrecto, pero no me lo muestra
        %>          
                <script>alert( "Hola " + <%=request.getAttribute("mensaje")%>) </script>
                <br>
                <!-- este es una caja de texto que puse para ver si estaba conectando correctamente al servlet y si conecta pero no muestra el alert-->
                <input type="text" name="txtResultado" value="<%=request.getAttribute("mensaje")%>" disabled/>
        <%
            }
                %>
    </div>
</body>
```

Osea si me muestra todo bien, hace la conexion con el servlet y valida y regresa la respuesta, sin embargo tengo problema con el alert al momento de ejecutar no aparece, solo me muestra el input abajo del alert que lo puse para verificar si hacia la conexion o no, y veo que el problema está en el alert, tengo mal la sintaxis del alert? desde ya Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>alert( "Hola " + <%=request.getAttribute("mensaje")%>)</script>
```

Si el mensaje es `mundo`, el HTML te queda:

```
<script>alert( "Hola " + mundo)</script>
```

Pero aquí `mundo` no es un literal sino que lo interpreta como una variable que no está definida, dando un error<sup>1</sup>

Puedes hacer directamente

```
<script>alert( "Hola <%=request.getAttribute("mensaje")%>")</script>
```

el tag se procesa en el servidor así que al navegador le llega

```
<script>alert( "Hola mundo")</script>
```

En todo caso, esto ejecuta el `alert` cuando el navegador todavía está procesando el HTML y la pantalla está a medio dibujar; queda mucho más elegante:

```
<script>
    window.onload= function() {
       alert( "Hola <%=request.getAttribute("mensaje")%>");
    };
 </script>
```

que le indica que cuando se haya terminado de cargar toda la página ejecute el código indicado.

---

<sup>1</sup>Los navegadores tienen una consola JS entre las herramientas de navegación, es muy útil. Y en cualquier caso siempre puedes mirar el código fuente de la página web generada para ver por donde van los tiros.

Comment: Woooowww muchas gracias! Me sirvió!!